# Parametric approach to estimating Average Treatment Effect on matched data with zelig()

Tags: r, multiple-regression, propensity-scores

I've been using the R packages MatchIt and Zelig to estimate the Average Treatment Effect (ATE) for a health care study with propensity score matching.

One approach for estimating the ATE is as follows:

```
m.out <- matchit(treatment ~ x1 + x2 + ...,
        method = "nearest", 
        ratio = 3,
        exact = c("x1"),
        data = psa_data)

z.out <- zelig(outcome ~ treatment + x1 + x2 + ...,
        data = match.data(m.out), model = "ls")

summary(z.out)
x.out <- setx(z.out, treatment=0)
x1.out <- setx(z.out, treatment=1)
s.out <- Zelig:::sim(z.out, x = x.out, x1 = x1.out)
summary(s.out)
```

Question: Can I use the coefficient on `treatment` in the `zelig()` regression, rather than the `sim()` output, as a parametric estimate of the ATE?

This is attractive because it allows me to pick apart which variables (and also interactions between the treatment & variables) are contributing to the ATE.

Comment: How do you justify throwing away some (how much?) of your data?  I think this matching approach throws away observations that are in the overlap region, i.e., that are "comparables" and should be analyzed.

Comment: @FrankHarrell With the data I'm working on now, thankfully we haven't had to throw out more than a few obs. because the control population is 20,000+ subjects while each of the treatment groups are only several hundred, so we have a "match rich" environment.

Comment: If you are set to use propensity scores I would suggest you do not use this approach and follow newer implementations. For example, [entropy balancing](http://web.stanford.edu/~jhain/Paper/PA2012.pdf) by Hainmueller (2012) (and please, go doubly-robust (ie. use covariate adjustment)). Model misspecification is a horrible issue when it comes to PSM. If you want something easily interpretable you might as well go with "Direct Estimation" as per Austin (2012) "[Using Ensemble-Based Methods for Directly Estimating Causal Effects](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3293511/)".

Comment: A side-note: "*This is attractive because it allows me to pick apart which variables (and also interactions between the treatment & variables) are contributing to the ATE.*" if you misspecify the model all bets are off. In addition it is worrisome to assert: "*x* contributes 25% of the ATE while *z* contributes 35%".

Comment: @usεr11852 Excellent, thank you for the links. I am seeing warnings: "Statistical Warning: The GIM test suggests this model is misspecified . . ." when I run `zelig()`. If I had more time I'd run thorough diagnostics, but presently I think I can live with my coefficient SEs being a bit too optimistic.

Comment: If you have 20,000 subjects and only several hundred exposed subjects how do you make maximum use of the 20,000 with the only deletions being non-comparable subjects?

Comment: @FrankHarrell My understanding is that non-comparable subjects should be included in a predictive model, but in a causal model we want to select control subjects who are as close as possible to treatment subjects. Plus this a situation where senior mgmt. liked the idea of using a nearest neighbor propensity score matching.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: I would never lilght-heartedly advocate deleting good data but to play devil's advocate: As treatment effect "causality" within a regression will boil down to a $t$-test with unequal sample sizes and unknown variances, the "big deal" is not to lose subjects from the smaller of the two samples; losing control subjects therefore is not very problematic (indeed some references eg. Ho et al. 2007, Sect. 5.1 argue that this decreased efficiency is worth the bias reduction and the subsequent covariate adjustment will take care of the bias. :D )

Comment: p.s. I'm not clear on why anyone would be interested in a sample-averaged effect as opposed to a covariate-specific effect.  Related to this is the problem on non-collabsability of odds ratios and other measures, if the outcome variable is not a standard continuous variable.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: It sounds like you need to ask your own question about why to use matching. Matching is a valid method, and you're not throwing out "perfectly good data", you're throwing out data that doesn't help identify the causal effect (i.e., control units far from the region of overlap). OP clearly has a continuous outcome variable, so the marginal treatment is equal to the conditional treatment effect and the estimand is collapsable. This is a fine analysis and it seems like you're devoted to critiquing it rather than helping OP perform it.

Comment: Incorrect.   Most matching algorithms throw away plenty of control units that are near the center of the overlap region.

Answer (score 3):

@RobertF you missed the fact that many comparable subjects close to treated subjects were excluded with this algorithm.  Regarding the "big deal" it is true that it's worse to lose subjects from the group with the lower sample size.  But I claim it is not really scientific to exclude informative data that were already collected.  This has nothing to do with bias.  It also has to do with non-reproducibility of analyses by others.

Comment: I fully agree with the non-reproducibility notion. That has been a pain with matching procedure in my experience too as among other things makes boostrapping procedures problematic as well. This has been touched by works like: [On the Failure of the Bootstrap for Matching Estimators](https://economics.mit.edu/files/11862) by Abadie & Imbens. (Obviously +1)

Comment: I actually disagree with this. The point of preprocessing in this way improves reproducibility by reducing model dependence. Reproducibility is hampered when different researchers use different models to analyze data from the sample population. Matching allows you not to have to make modeling assumptions.

Comment: Matching makes assumptions, is inefficient, and is dependent on how you sort the dataset, and is not reproducible in the general sense.  So I could not disagree more.